# Google Sheets IF&AND functions giving contradicting results

Tags: google-sheets, formula, array-formulas

I am having some trouble with a formula in Google sheets. For me it just doesn't make any sense, why it is working in one place and not another.
So, here is my sample [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ELWgxqPSOuyvLipsfdGYkF97TWH5szvtIKxQTY3porE/edit?usp=sharing)

My aim is to duplicate results in column D to column E, but with a filter built-in which filters on column A, company.

This is the formula which is working fine:

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,Unique(IF(B4=B:B,C:C,""))))
```

And I need the IF part to take another condition, which is A=A:A

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,Unique(IF(AND(A4=A:A,B4=B:B),C:C,"NOT GOOD"))))
```

So I thought AND will do it as it does elsewhere. But in this particular case, this just doesn't seem to work and gives an error every time.
I checked and the logic seems fine based on this (giving the expected results):

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,Unique(IF(AND(TRUE,TRUE),C:C,"NOT GOOD"))))
```

The strange part is that if I select the IF foormula, it tells me that both of the conditions in AND are true, but it still gives me the FALSE result.
[showing true, but results in false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHV8o.png)

I am having a hard time understanding why this is the case?? I hope you could help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey there, I think i can help demonstrate the solution/ issue in the sheet if you make it editable instead of just View Only.

Comment: @MattKing, thank you, I made it editable!

Comment: you can't use AND() in array boolean logic like you're trying to do. You need to replace AND() with multiplication and OR() with addition. so for example instead of AND(A4=A:A,B4=B:B) you would write (A4=A:A)*(B4=B:B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a new tab called MK.Help and placed this formula in cell B2:

```
=UNIQUE('Combined Job Catalogue'!A3:B)
```

Then this formula in cell D3 and dragged down a couple dozen rows:

```
=IF(C3="",,JOIN(", ",UNIQUE(FILTER('Combined Job Catalogue'!C:C,'Combined Job Catalogue'!A:A=B3,'Combined Job Catalogue'!B:B=C3))))
```

Was that the goal?

Comment: Hey, thank you very much! This works perfectly.
On the other hand, I still don't know what is the logic flaw in my formula :(

Comment: you can't use AND() in array boolean logic like you're trying to do.  You need to replace AND() with multiplication and OR() with addition.  so for example instead of AND(A4=A:A,B4=B:B)     you would write (A4=A:A)*(B4=B:B)